# ReactJS 5.3.0 not loading from unpkg.com

Tags: facebook, reactjs

We have been using the following library for months:
https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.min.js

Yes - I know we can just reference 15.3 and get the URL rewrite to the latest, but they released a breaking change.  That's another issue for another day.  Don't get distracted.

Yesterday this simply stopped working.  You'll notice that if you load the URL mentioned, that the file is TRUNCATED.  Simply cuts off.  This made everything we use react with break.  Interestingly, if you go to the following URL (without the .js extension) - things work.

https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.min

My question is - what the heck happened?  Why did the URL we've been using for 8 months suddenly stop working, and who can we get to fix it.  In the interim, we had a copy locally that we've started referencing (which we probably should have been doing to begin with, since we don't want the automatic upgrade).  When things like this happen, who do you inform?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you'll find the answer as to why this file is no longer working here but based off of the website you could reached out to the creator on twitter: https://twitter.com/mjackson

On the website it says:

> SUPPORT
>
> unpkg is a free, best-effort service and cannot provide any uptime or
>   support guarantees.

i.e. you should probably only use this link if you are messing around with a small project and shouldn't be used for any website where you actually care about the uptime of the site.

Comment: Unpkg messaged me on twitter. They cleared the cache and the file loads now. We did bring the file down locally though.